# Как правильно зашифровать данные для оплаты через Tinkoff finishAuthorize?

Tags: node.js, шифрование, nestjs

пытаюсь зашифровать данные. в Nest.js по этой инструкции

> - Объект CardData собирается в виде списка «ключ=значение» (разделитель «;»), зашифровывается открытым ключом (X509 RSA 2048),
>   получившееся бинарное значение кодируется в Base64. Открытый ключ
>   генерируется Банком и выдается при регистрации терминала. Все поля
>   обязательны.

```
const cardData = 'PAN=2203704112091484;ExpDate=0434;CardHolder=INAV PETROV;CVV=218';

    const key = new NodeRSA();
    key.importKey(this._publicKey, 'pkcs8-public');
    const encrypted = key.encrypt(cardData, 'base64');
```

но выдает Ошибка шифрования карточных данных.

может сталкивался кто с такой проблемой и функционалом и укажите на проблемное место

Comment: а так https://gist.github.com/sohamkamani/b14a9053551dbe59c39f83e25c829ea7#file-rsa-js-L26 ?

Comment: не срабатывает

Error: error:1E08010C:DECODER routines::unsupported
    at Object.publicEncrypt (node:internal/crypto/cipher:79:12)

Comment: я сгенерировал ключ так https://pastebin.com/8WnKi7jj, потом зашифровал данные так https://pastebin.com/k9HjpC3N. попробуйте так же

Comment: ключ мне выдает банк + можно взять готовый ключ здесь https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/rsa-encryption-decryption

но с этим открытым ключом у меня не работает crypto

Comment: Странно, но заработало когда свой ключ положил в файл, и выполнил след код
const publicKey = fs.readFileSync('./rsaprivkey_public.key');
    const encryptedData = crypto.publicEncrypt(
      {
        key: Buffer.from(publicKey),
        padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_PADDING,
      },
      Buffer.from(cardData),
    );

 но не могу понять почему так

Comment: я думаю, что при копировании тела сертификата в исходный код, вы потеряли что-то типа переносов строк. https://stackoverflow.com/a/74668003/4496422